# Sqoop --where condition with multiple clause

Tags: oracle, hadoop, where-clause, sqoop

I'm trying to get data from Oracle and import in Hadoop table. I'm making changes inn existing sqoop, i have to use --where to filter the record. For now we have in where date=somedate condition, now i need to add another condition like date = somedate and status ='Active'. I have make this change in --where. I'm not allowed to use --query .

Can you guys help me on this ?

Comment: FWIW, Sqoop is a retired Apache project, and it's recommended that you use other tools for this

Answer (score 0):

You can try like this

--query "select * from table where status = 'Active' AND date=somedate AND $CONDITIONS"

Answer (score 0):

use `--where` condition wrapped in double quotes like below.

```
--where " date = somedate and status ='Active'"
```

And good news is you can add as many conditions as possible. In fact you can add subquery as well - it should be syntactically correct in database.

Answer (score 0):

This syntax is helpful for me:

--query "select * from table where date=somedate AND status ='Active' AND ($CONDITIONS)"

there is no need to use --where.